# Buscar registro pelo cpf ASP .NET CORE 3.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, linq, entity-framework-core

Criei um CRUD simples usando ASP .NET CORE 3.0 usando EF. Todas as operações básicas do CRUD estão rodando normal.

Tentei criar um método manualmente para pesquisar um registro pelo CPF do cliente conforme código abaixo, mas ele sempre me retorna NotFound.

Como eu poderia fazer um método simples para pesquisar pelo CPF e retornar o objeto Cliente?

Abaixo o código do Cliente

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClienteController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly APIDBContext _context;

        public ClienteController(APIDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Cliente>>> GetClientes()
        {
            return await _context.Clientes.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> GetCliente(int id)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return cliente;
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente/search/12345678901
        [HttpGet("{cpf}")]
        [Route("search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> SearchCliente(string cpf)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(cpf);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return cliente;
        }

        // PUT: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCliente(int id, Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (id != cliente.clienteID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClienteExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Cliente
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostCliente(Cliente cliente)
        {
            _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.clienteID }, cliente);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> DeleteCliente(int id)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);
            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return cliente;
        }

        private bool ClienteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Clientes.Any(e => e.clienteID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: e como o `FindAsync` vai saber que está passando o cpf e não id? precisa informar isso, senão ele não consegue saber, precisaria fazer algo como `_context.Clientes.Where(c => c.CPF == cpf).Single();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Find` (e sua versão assíncrona) apenas buscam por chaves primárias. Para buscar por outros campos, você precisa usar outros métodos.

Neste caso, você pode usar o método `FirstOrDefaultAsync`

```
await _context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => x.CPF == algumCpf)
```

Comment: @LINK perfeito! Deu certinho desse jeito...

Comment: Eu testei pelo POSTMAN e enviei o numero do CPF no body, desse forma ele retornou o cliente... Mas quando envio pela URL ou pelo ANGULAR só retorna NotFound. Já tentei converter para ToString, mas não adiantou também... Por quê será que acontece isso?

Comment: @RDamazio Difícil responder sem saber detalhes. Tente abrir outra pergunta com um [mcve]

Comment: Vou fazer isso e colocar o código